# MYSQL filter by multiple values in same cell?

Tags: php, mysql, search, cell

MYSQL can do the next?

My Terms = `a b c`

My Query = `SELECT * FROM pages WHERE`content`CONTAINS (a AND b AND c)`

I need make a query with multiple terms in a page (a searcher). If I've a cell with `"1a2b3c"` this must be filtered and if other cell have `"1a2b4d9i"` so the second mustn't be filtered.

Also, if is possible, I want filter by words. Like a `"1a2b3c" --> "1 a 2 b 3 c"`, and won't filter if the text it's joined.

I test this code

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE "
                      ."(`title` LIKE '%$s%' OR "
                      ."`title` LIKE '%$s' OR "
                      ."`title` LIKE '$s%' OR"
                      ."`content` LIKE '%$s%' OR "
                      ."`content` LIKE '%$s' OR "
                      ."`content` LIKE '$s%') "
                      ."AND `name` != 'inicio' "
                      ."AND `name` != 'contactenos' "
                      ."AND `name` != '404' "
                      ."AND `name` != '403' "
                      ."AND `name` != 'login'");
```

With one value works great, but with 2 or more values it can't find something.

Also I tried `(a,b,c)` and `a|b|c` with `AGAINST`, `REGEX` and other but I couldn't make it works.

---

EDIT 1:
If I search "foo bar" and my php code convert it to an array, How can I do to write on MYSQL? I need if I search `"foo bar"` and my text it's `"the foo bar is awesome"` and other text is `"the foo is worst"` only print the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your query a lot shorter.
You could use something like this

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE "
                      ."`title` LIKE '%".$s."%' OR "
                      ."`content` LIKE '%".$s."%' OR "
                      ."AND `name` != 'inicio' "
                      ."AND `name` != 'contactenos' "
                      ."AND `name` != '404' "
                      ."AND `name` != '403' "
                      ."AND `name` != 'login'");
```

You could use GROUP BY to prevent multiply results:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE "
                      ."`title` LIKE '%".$s."%' OR "
                      ."`content` LIKE '%".$s."%' OR "
                      ."AND `name` != 'inicio' "
                      ."AND `name` != 'contactenos' "
                      ."AND `name` != '404' "
                      ."AND `name` != '403' "
                      ."AND `name` != 'login'") GROUP BY title,content;
```

For Better Overview :

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE "
                  ."`title` LIKE '%".$s."%' OR "
                  ."`content` LIKE '%".$s."%' OR "
                  ."AND `name` NOT IN('inicio','contactenos','404','403','login') GROUP BY title,content;
```

But please sanitize your variables before using in the query ;)

Comment: Thanks for answer and remove code. But the problem it's same. If I search "foo bar" and my php code convert it to an array, How can I do to write on MYSQL?
I need if I search "foo bar" and my text it's "the foo bar is awesome" and other text is "the foo is worst" only print the first.